# Removing Duplicate Documents from collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to remove duplicate documents from my collection. However, it needs to remove duplicated by name but not in the same category. For example;

Collection= Product

```
Product {
 id: ...
 name:"Apple"
 category:"Fruit"
}

Product {
 id: ...
 name:"Apple"
 category:"Fruit"
}

Product {
 id: ...
 name:"Apple"
 category:"New Fruit"
}
```

So the end result would be two documents. Both have the name Apple but one is of category 'New Fruit' and one is of 'Fruit'

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove duplicate record using **foreach** keyword and find the duplicate record and delete record, Please see following code

```
db.demo1.find({}).forEach( function(myDoc) { 
    var condname=myDoc.name;
    var condcat=myDoc.cat;
    var countRecord=db.demo1.find( { name: condname, cat: condcat } ).count()
    if(countRecord > 1)
    {
      db.demo1.deleteMany( {_id:{$ne: myDoc._id}, name: condname, cat: condcat });
    }

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following aggregation query collects the `_id`s grouped by the `name` and `category` fields. The `$project` stage retains only the duplicate `_id`s for deletion. Finally, the *delete* operation removes duplicate documents queried by their `_id`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: { n: "$name", c: "$category" },
          all_ids: { $addToSet: "$_id" }
      } 
  },
  { 
      $project: {
          dup_ids: { $slice: [ "$all_ids", 1, 9999999 ] },
          _id: 0
       }
  }
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.deleteMany( { _id: { $in: doc.dup_ids } } ) )
```